Simple CMOS OR gate in Proteus
CMOS OR gate in Proteus:

must be +0V on output, but +4.12 was detected:



must be +5V on output, but +4.15 was detected:



First, you need to connect the N channel MOSFET Source terminal to GND and the P channel MOSFET Source to VCC. Now you have it upside down (backward). And from what I can see your circuit is a NOR gate.

And if you want to have an OR gate you need to build this circuit instead:


I did in correspond with your example. It work, but as NOR gate. See got truth table and screenshots from Proteus by link: https://telegra.ph/Answer-to-user-G36-08-15

Take a look at my updated answer.

Yes, updated circuit work as OR (you added not gate on output), but can't be created CMOS OR gate using only 4 CMOS? I'm more interested in how to fix my circuit, because it should work.

No, you cannot build a "normal" OR gate using only 4 CMOS transistors.

Apparently, you applied the voltages in reverse.
Q12's and Q13's body diodes are forward-biased. So I'm surprised you are getting 4.15V there (probably because of the MOSFET models you use) because the effective circuit is like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R_Q14 and R_Q15 represent the resistances across D and S of the respective MOSFETs for a Vgs of 10 - 5 = 5 VDC.
The arrangement should be the same as shown in G36's answer.
